# A channel is necessary to connect an application to Websphere MQ v8?

Tags: jms, ibm-mq

So, I need to create a Websphere MQ setup in order to receive messages from an application hosted on a Websphere Application Server.

I already created the JMS objects at MQ, using MQ Explorer. Also created the QM and the necessary queues. Ah, important info: The application user point-to-point communication.

What is the purpose of the channels at Websphere? They are only used to link different Queue Managers or they can be used also to connect a client application to MQ?

Which information the application must inform to connect to a queue at MQ?

Answer (score 3):

In IBM MQ (formerly WebSphere MQ), channels represent a communication link between two components. There are three distinct types of channels used in IBM MQ:

- Message channel, which is a unidirectional pathway between two Queue Managers.
- MQI channel, which is a bidirectional channel that connects an MQI (Message Queue Interface) client and a Queue Manager.
- AMQP channel*, which is again bidirectional and used to connect between an AMQP (Advanced Message Queuing Protocol) client and a Queue Manager.

If you are new to IBM MQ, take a look at the IBM Redbook, [WebSphere MQ Primer - An Introduction to Messaging and WebSphere MQ](http://www.redbooks.ibm.com/abstracts/redp0021.html).

'Channels' at the IBM Documentation for MQ: https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSFKSJ_9.0.0/com.ibm.mq.explorer.doc/e_channels.htm

*AMQP clients are supported from MQ v8.0.0.4 and above.

Comment: And for the sake of completeness, you don't always need a channel, when the QM and the application using it is on the same server you can use bindings mode connection too.